# Is there a way to group up multiple fields in Tableau to use as on data piece?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I am trying to learn all about Data Visualization and Tableau, so I was wondering if one can combine multiple fields into one, and how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Tableau is quite versatile. There are many ways to combine multiple fields, for many meanings of the word "combine".    If you just want to add some numeric fields together to make a new variable, or string some text fields together to make a larger text field, you can do that by defining a "computed field".

These videos are free and you can watch them to get an idea of what can be done.
Here's a 23 minute overview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6py0jyZc7K4
I see the short intro video on Tableau's site isn't working right now.

Here's another walk-through of what's possible
https://www.tableau.com/learn/training/20213

Wade